# Missing values in $_POST variables

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form with around 65 input fields. The form uses `POST` method, and upon submission the fields are directed to a php script for database entry.nothing scientific.

However, there are few `POST` variables which generate `undefined index` warning and have empty values in corresponding database columns. I cannot seem to figure out why are few variables are generating undefined index warning while rest are doing just fine.

For an example, following is the `html` and `php` script for retrieving values using POST variables. `cfrom` generates the `undefined index` warning while `cjnb` works just fine.
HTML:

```
      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Current Job Nature of Business
      <input placeholder="" id="cjnb" name="cjnb" tabindex="27">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Joining Date
      <input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" id="cfrom" name="cfrom" tabindex="28" >
    </label>
  </div>
```

PHP:

```
$cjnb=$_POST['cjnb'];
$cfrom=$_POST['cfrom'];
```

I tried using `isset` and it sets the variable to empty value probably because it does not find a value in `$_POST['cfrom']`, however, i am entering a value in the `cfrom` input value.

Please Help!

UPDATE: FULL FORM

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
  <title>Horizontal Application Form - Template Monster Demo</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Jake Rocheleau">


  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.tmimgcdn.com/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://static.tmimgcdn.com/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/switchery.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/switchery.min.js"></script>





</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">


    <h1>dfsdfsdf</h1>
    <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|sdfdfs</h2>

 <!-- <form onsubmit="return false">-->
  <form action="save.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Position of Interest</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>



      <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Position of Interest
      <select tabindex="1" id="poi" name="poi">
        <option>Vacant Position 1</option>
        <option>Vacant Position 2</option>
        <option>Vacant Position 3</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>  
      <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      City Applied For
      <select tabindex="2" id="cityapplied" name="cityapplied">
        <option>Karachi</option>
        <option>Hyderabad</option>
        <option>Lahore</option>
        <option>Peshawar</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div> 

<!--<p>Personal Information</p>-->
  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Personal Information</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>


  <div class="col-1">
    <label>
      Name
      <input placeholder="What is your full name?" id="name" name="name" tabindex="3">
    </label>
  </div>                                                                              


  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Phone Number
      <input placeholder="What is the best # to reach you?" id="phone" name="phone" tabindex="4">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Email
      <input placeholder="What is your e-mail address?" id="email" name="email" tabindex="5">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Alternate Contact
      <input placeholder="What is your alternate number?" id="res" name="res" tabindex="6">
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Date Of Birth
      <input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="dob" name="dob" tabindex="7">
    </label>
  </div>
<div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Place Of Birth
      <input placeholder="Place Of Birth" id="pob" name="pob" tabindex="8">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      CNIC
      <input placeholder="xxxxx-xxxxxxx-x" id="cnic" name="cnic" tabindex="9">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Marital Status
      <input placeholder="Please type your marital status here" id="ms" name="ms" tabindex="10">
    </label>
  </div>

    <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Present Address
      <input placeholder="Your current address" id="pa" name="pa" tabindex="11">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      City of Residence
      <input placeholder="Your current city" id="cor" name="cor" tabindex="12">
    </label>
  </div>




<!--<p> Academic and Professional Qualification </p>-->
  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Academic and Professional Qualification</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>



  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Highest Degree Level
      <select tabindex="13" id="hdl" name="hdl">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
<label>
      Highest Degree Title
      <select tabindex="14" id="hdt" name="hdt">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Highest Degree Discipline
      <select tabindex="15" id="hdd" name="hdd">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Year Passed
      <input placeholder="YYYY" id="hyp" name="hyp" tabindex="16">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Division/GPA/Grade
     <input placeholder="Division/GPA/Grade" id="hdgg" name="hdgg" tabindex="17">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Highest Degree Institution
      <select tabindex="18" id="hdi" name="hdi">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Secondary Degree Level
      <select tabindex="19" id="sdl" name="sdl">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
<label>
      Secondary Degree Title
      <select tabindex="20" id="sdt" name="sdt">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Secondary Degree Discipline
      <select tabindex="21" id="sdd" name="sdd">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Year Passed
      <input placeholder="YYYY" id="syp" name="syp" tabindex="22">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Division/GPA/Grade
     <input placeholder="Division/GPA/Grade" id="sdgg" name="sdgg" tabindex="23">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>
      Secondary Degree Institution
      <select tabindex="24" id="sdi" name="sdi">
        <option>Doctrate</option>
        <option>Masters</option>
        <option>Bachelors</option>
        <option>Diploma</option>
        <option>Certification</option>
        <option>Intermediate</option>
        <option>Matriculation</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>


<!--<p>Employement History</p>-->

  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Employement History</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>

    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Current Company
      <input placeholder="Where do you currently work?" id="ccompany" name="ccompany" tabindex="25">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Current Designation
      <input placeholder="What is your current designation?" id="cdesig" name="cdesig" tabindex="26">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Current Job Nature of Business
      <input placeholder="" id="cjnb" name="cjnb" tabindex="27">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Joining Date
      <input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" id="cfrom" name="cfrom" tabindex="28" >
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Required Notice Period
       <select tabindex="29" id="rnp" name="rnp">
        <option>7 days</option>
        <option>14 days</option>
        <option>30 days</option>
        <option>More than 30 days</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Last Company
      <input placeholder="Where did you work before your current company?" id="lcompany" name="lcompany" tabindex="29">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Last Designation
      <input placeholder="What was your desingation at your last company?" id="ld" name="ld" tabindex="30">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Last Job Nature of Business
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="ljnb" name="lnjb" tabindex="31">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Joining Date
      <input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" id="LFrom" name="LFrom" tabindex="32">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Leaving Date
      <input placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" id="LTo" name="LTo" tabindex="33">
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Willingness to relocate anywhere in Pakistan
      <select tabindex="34" id="relocate" name="relocate">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
        <option>Depends</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Years Of Experience
      <input placeholder="Years of Experience" id="yoe" name="yoe" tabindex="35">
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Professional Preference</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
  <label>
      First Field Preference
      <select tabindex="36" id="ffp" name="ffp">
        <option>Field 1</option>
        <option>FIeld 2</option>
        <option>Field 3</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Second Field Preference
      <select tabindex="37" id="sfp" name="sfp">
        <option>Field 1</option>
        <option>FIeld 2</option>
        <option>Field 3</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Third Field Preference
      <select tabindex="38" id="tfp" name="tfp">
        <option>Field 1</option>
        <option>FIeld 2</option>
        <option>Field 3</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>



  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Salary Details</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>


    <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Gross Monthly Salary
      <input placeholder="Current Salary" id="csal" name="csal" tabindex="39">
    </label>
  </div>
<div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Expected Salary
      <input placeholder="Expected Salary" id="esal" name="esal" tabindex="40">
    </label>
  </div>


    <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Provident Fund (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" id="pf" name="pf" tabindex="41">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Gratuity (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" id="gr" name="gr" tabindex="42">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      LFA (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="lfa" name="lfa" tabindex="43">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Medical OPD Limit (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="mol" name="mol" tabindex="44">
    </label>
  </div>



      <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Incentive (PKR)
      <input placeholder="If any" id="incentive" name="incentive" tabindex="45">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Bonus/Variable Pay (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" id="bv" name="bv" tabindex="46">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Tel/Mobile Allowance (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="tmo" name="tmo" tabindex="47">
    </label>
  </div>



    <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Car/Motorcycle
      <input placeholder="" id="car" name="car" tabindex="48">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Fuel Limit (Ltrs.)
      <input placeholder="" id="fl" name="fl" tabindex="49">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      Vehicle Maintenance (PKR)
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="vm" name="vm" tabindex="50">
    </label>
  </div>


      <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Group Life Insurance
      <select tabindex="24" id="gpl" name="gpl">
        <option>Yes</option>
        <option>No</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Furnishing
      <input placeholder="" id="furnish" name="furnish" tabindex="51">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Leaves (Days)
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="leaves" name="leaves" tabindex="52">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    <label>
      Other Benefits
      <input placeholder="If any" type="text" id="ob" name="ob" tabindex="53">
    </label>
  </div>


  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>References</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Reference Name 1
      <input placeholder="" id="rn1" name="rn1" tabindex="54">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Contact
      <input placeholder="" id="rcontact1" name="rcontact1" tabindex="55">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Email
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="remail1" name="remail1" tabindex="56">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Designation
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="rdesig1" name="rdesig1" tabindex="57">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Company
      <input placeholder="" id="rcompany1" name="rcompany1" tabindex="58">
    </label>
  </div>


      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Reference Name 2
      <input placeholder="" id="rname2" name="rname2" tabindex="59">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Contact
      <input placeholder="" id="rcontact2" name="rcontact2" tabindex="60">
    </label>
  </div>
      <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Email
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="remail2" name="remail2" tabindex="61">
    </label>
  </div>
    <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Designation
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="rdesig2" name="rdesig2" tabindex="62">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <label>
      Company
      <input placeholder="" type="text" id="rcompany2" name="rcompany2" tabindex="63">
    </label>
  </div>  

  <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1" style="background-color:#f4f4f3;">
<label>Uploads</label>
</div>
 <div class="col-1" style="height:30px;">
  </div>  


      <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Upload Your Resume
      <input placeholder="" type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" tabindex="64">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label>
      Upload Your Photo
      <input placeholder="" type="file" id="fileToUpload2" name="fileToUpload2" tabindex="65">
    </label>
  </div>  



  <div class="col-submit">
    <button class="submitbtn">Submit Form</button>
  </div>

  </form>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.js-switch'));

elems.forEach(function(html) {
  var switchery = new Switchery(html);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2: PHP CODE - RELEVANT PARTS ONLY

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['mySubmitButton'])) {

    // All the posted value
    $cfrom = htmlentities($_POST['cfrom']); // Escape your post values

}
echo "here we go:".$cfrom;

.
.
.
$ccompany=$_POST['ccompany'];
$cdesig=$_POST['cdesig'];
$cjnb=$_POST['cjnb'];
$cfrom=$_POST['cfrom'];
$rnp=$_POST['rnp'];
$lcompany=$_POST['lcompany'];
$ld=$_POST['ld'];
$lnjb=$_POST['lnjb'];
.
.
.

?>
```

UPDATE 3: ERROR LOG

```
[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] **********************DEBUG************************

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cfrom in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 23

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 101

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   2. mysql_connect() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:101

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: cfrom in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 146

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: LFrom in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 151

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: LTo in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 152

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lfa in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 162

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: mol in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 163

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: tmo in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 166

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: vm in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 169

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: gpl in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 170

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: leaves in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 172

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ob in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 173

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: remail1 in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 176

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rdesig1 in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 177

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rcompany1 in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 178

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: remail2 in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 181

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rdesig2 in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 182

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rcompany2 in C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php on line 183

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP Stack trace:

[24-Oct-2015 14:48:23 Europe/Paris] PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\careers\save.php:0
```

Comment: Can you post your full form please?

Comment: Are you checking if they are set using `isset` before using them?

Comment: Sounds like typo errors or something similar.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans: added.

Comment: didn't expect a form that long lol..

Comment: lol, i was avoiding it for a reason. but if you go through it, there is nothing different between `cjnb` field, which is doing fine and `cfrom` which is missing from `$_POST` variables.

Comment: @arkascha : have spent hours. couldn't spot one. wanna try?

Comment: @Salik How should I? You did not post your code!

Comment: All the posted variables should be inside the if statement...

Answer (score 1):

Can't see any problems with the current provided code.

A suggestion would be to give a `name="mySubmitButton"` to the submit button and add `type="submit"` attribute.

Then the PHP would be:

```
if (isset($_POST['mySubmitButton'])) {

    // All the posted value
    $cfrom = htmlentities($_POST['cfrom']); // Escape your post values

}
```

Comment: still the same undefined index warning.

Comment: Could you share your php file too? But only the needed part maybe :p

Comment: @JeroenBellemans What? No! Why would one want to use `htmlentities()` on post variables?

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking the request in the network tab of your developer tools if the above mentioned field isnt there, that means you have a typo in your html.

Comment: the field `cfrom` does not show i network log, while other fields do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print all the post values using print_r($_POST); on top of your save.php script.

I tried the same form and i got the value ($_POST['cfrom']) which you mentioned above.

If you also getting the value when you print the post data then you might be doing something wrong below the code.

Comment: it is printing other variables but still gives `undefined index` with print_r for cfrom.

Comment: <input type="submit" name="mySubmitButton" value="Submit" />

Comment: And if you are using mysql database use mysql_real_escape_string(< PHP 5.5.0) or mysqli_real_escape_string() for greater versions of PHP to validate input fields

Comment: thanks, but i corrected the submit button name. still no use. and i am stuck with retrieving $_POST variable values into php variables. Will recheck sql once i get there.

Answer (score 0):

When you get undefined index, it usually means your form input name dont match the $_POST index, Suggestion is to log the variables and see what you are getting:

```
error_log('**********************DEBUG************************');
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$postBack = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
error_log($postBack);
error_log('**********************DEBUG************************');
```

Then copy paste from the log to create your validation:

```
if(isset($_POST['ccompany'],$_POST['cdesig'],$_POST['cjnb'],$_POST['cfrom'],$_POST['rnp'],$_POST['lcompany'],$_POST['ld'],$_POST['lnjb'])){
    $ccompany=$_POST['ccompany'];
    $cdesig=$_POST['cdesig'];
    $cjnb=$_POST['cjnb'];
    $cfrom=$_POST['cfrom'];
    $rnp=$_POST['rnp'];
    $lcompany=$_POST['lcompany'];
    $ld=$_POST['ld'];
    $lnjb=$_POST['lnjb'];
}else{
    echo "missing variable check log";
}
```

Comment: it points to cfrom, which has the same name. the input feels right above and below it are working just fine.

Comment: try adding type="text" to your inputs

Comment: it was there, before i removed it to see if it can work without it. didnt make a difference either way.

Comment: are you saying you can see cfrom in your log but it still give you undefined?

Comment: i get cfrom in error log with same undefined index warning.

Comment: please check updated my question with log.i removed all other variables but kept cfrom just to keep it simple.

Comment: The logs did not print any value, and all the other ones are undefined as well. It is clear your are not getting the POST

Comment: No, i only kept one variable `cfrom` to be logged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93246/discussion-between-meda-and-salik).